# Can't update form field via ajax on submit

Tags: forms, ajax

I have two entity types -- `video` and `video progress`.

I've got a form on `video` nodes with a field that is populated with the id of a `video progress` entity that references the current node. If this field is empty when the form is submitted, then I am generating a new `video progress` entity in the submit handler, and am trying to populate my form field value with this new entity id. This form is hidden from the user and is updated dynamically as the user watches a video via jQuery.

My issue is that no matter what I try, I cannot get the submit or ajax callbacks to rebuild my field. Here are the relevant portions of my code.

```
function video_progress_tracking_form($form, &$form_state) {
  // $progress_id is already set

  $form['progress_id'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Video progress entity id'),
    '#default_value' => $progress_id,
    '#element_validate' => array('element_validate_integer_positive'), 
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'video_progress_tracking_form_ajax_handler',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
  );

  return $form;
}

function video_progress_tracking_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
  if(empty($form_state['progress_id'])) {
    // If a video progress entity doesn't exist, we need to create one
    $entity_type = 'video_progress';
    $entity = entity_create($entity_type, array('type' => 'video_progress'));
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $entity);
    $wrapper->save();

    // Pass our new values into the form for further updating
    $form_state['values']['progress_id'] = $wrapper->id->value();  
  }
}

function video_progress_tracking_form_ajax_handler(&$form, &$form_state) {
  return $form['progress_id'];
}
```

I have also tried, among other things:

- Setting a `#value` when initially building the form on `$form['progress_id']` with a ternary operator so that if there is a form_state value for the field then that is set
- Setting `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE` in both callbacks
- Returning the entire form instead of just this single field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told the form API *where* to render the content you're returning in the AJAX callback.

That takes the form of a prefix/suffix on the element itself, with a predictable HTML ID:

```
$html_id = drupal_html_id('foo');
$form['progress_id'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Video progress entity id'),
  '#default_value' => $progress_id,
  '#element_validate' => array('element_validate_integer_positive'), 
  '#prefix' => '<div id="' . $html_id . '">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
```

And providing the AJAX-ified element with the ID of the wrapping HTML:

```
$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'Submit',
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'video_progress_tracking_form_ajax_handler',
    'effect' => 'fade',
    'wrapper' => $html_id,
  ),
);
```

You will need to add/keep `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;` in the submit handler (not the AJAX callback). To isolate that functionality you may wish to add a specific `#submit` handler array to your submit button.

Comment: Can you think of why it still wouldn't be working? I've added the prefix and suffix to my field, the wrapper to #ajax, and `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE` to the submit function, but the field is remaining empty after submit. I've verified that `$form_state['values']['progress_id']` is set in my AJAX callback prior to `return $form['progress_id']`.

Comment: It also doesn't seem to make a difference whether I designate `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE` in the default callback or within a secondary callback (if that matters).

Comment: It might come down to where you're getting `$progress_id` from in the form builder. That should be coming from `$form_state['values']['progress_id']` if it's set, is that what you've got? You have a small (unrelated) bug in the submit handler BTW, you should be testing `$form_state['values']['progress_id']` rather than `$form_state['progress_id']`.

Comment: Ah, got it. I forgot to move some logic into an else condition so `$progress_id` was getting reset before it hit my field -- gah! Thanks! Good catch on the bug -- it's actually commented already on my end to make sure my entities were generated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$form['progress_id'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Video progress entity id'),
        '#default_value' => $progress_id,
        '#element_validate' => array('element_validate_integer_positive'), 
      );
      $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Submit',
        '#ajax' => array(
          'callback' => 'video_progress_tracking_form_ajax_handler',
          'effect' => 'fade',
        ),
      );
```

by

```
 $form['progress_id'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="my-div-ajax">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',

    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Video progress entity id'),
    '#default_value' => $progress_id,
    '#element_validate' => array('element_validate_integer_positive'), 
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
    '#ajax' => array(

      'callback' => 'video_progress_tracking_form_ajax_handler',
      'wrapper' => 'my-div-ajax',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
  );
```